# Jsoup - how to find out elements size

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am confused with jsoup API. My code parses a table with 4 cells. But I found an occurence where three cells are merged into the single one and my code fails there because the child at position 3 does not exist.

```
String sMminutesLeft = row.child(3).text();
```

The `element.child(x)` returns a filtered list of child elements, e.g. only tags, not text nodes. But `element.childNodesCount()` will return a count of all elements including text nodes. I expected 4 but I receive 9 (lots of newlines are included).

I found `element.getElementsByTag("TD")` returning `Elements` object. This object acts like a container but it does not have any `size()` method.

How can I safely find out number of TDs under the current TR element? Implementing `NodeVisitor` seems like overkill to me.

Comment: I have selected a workaround try-catch IndexOutOfBounds originally and later I ahve realized I can search for colspan attribute. But I would still prefer enhancement of API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround but as I feel the API is incomplete, I have created a pull request that adds new method to get the number of filtered children that is complementary to child(int). Here it is: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/pull/1291